# limit point of the infinite bounded set

Tags: real-analysis

I read one theorem stating that 'every infinite bounded set has the greatest and smallest limit points,' but I consider the set $\left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. This set is bounded as $0$ and $1$ are it's lower and upper bounds and the set is infinite too but it has only one limit point $0$...what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is exactly one limit point, the greatest limit point is $0$ and the smallest limit point is $0$ as well.

There is no contradiction in the example that you proposed.